# Unable to create ionic 3 project instead of 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I tied to create an ionic project v3 using the following command

```
ionic start myApp tabs
```

but the final result was an ionic v4 project.

How can I force ionic to crate a v3 project instead of v4 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to uninstall ionic globlally first:

```
npm uninstall ionic -g
```

then install a ionic 3 version you like so:

```
npm install ionic@3.20.0 -g
```

Now run

```
ionic info
```

you should see the **ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0**

Now you can install an ionic 3 app using the command you tried.

Comment: you do not need to uninstall current version of ionic to use ionic 3. Just add --type=ionic-angular

Answer (score 9):

You can use the below command to create a Ionic 3 Project when you have Ionic 4 installed

```
ionic start ProjectName blank --type=ionic-angular
```

Answer (score 7):

For reference, you can do this without downgrading your Ionic CLI.  Notice that `--type=ionic-angular` is the Ionic 4 CLI way of saying "Ionic 3".  Here's a reference to that:
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/3862

If you run `ionic start --list` it will show the available templates and project types.  For project type, `angular` would be Ionic 4, `ionic-angular` would be Ionic 3, and `ionic1` is actually well named :-)

```
name     | project type  | description
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
blank    | angular       | A blank starter project
sidemenu | angular       | A starting project with a side menu with navigation in the content area
tabs     | angular       | A starting project with a simple tabbed interface
tabs     | ionic-angular | A starting project with a simple tabbed interface
blank    | ionic-angular | A blank starter project
sidemenu | ionic-angular | A starting project with a side menu with navigation in the content area
super    | ionic-angular | A starting project complete with pre-built pages, providers and best practices for Ionic development.
tutorial | ionic-angular | A tutorial based project that goes along with the Ionic documentation
aws      | ionic-angular | AWS Mobile Hub Starter
tabs     | ionic1        | A starting project for Ionic using a simple tabbed interface
blank    | ionic1        | A blank starter project for Ionic
sidemenu | ionic1        | A starting project for Ionic using a side menu with navigation in the content area
maps     | ionic1        | An Ionic starter project using Google Maps and a side menu
```

Also note that you will not start out with cordova assets (e.g. `config.xml`).  Adding a platform for the first time will pull that stuff in though.